# Multiple email input

Tags: terminology, html, input

In Live Mail, and I believe Google Mail too, you can specify multiple recipients within the same input box and separate them with either a tab, a space or a comma in some cases. This is also the same for the tags box on this website to allow you to specify multiple tags and you can remove them.

What I wondered was whether this type of input has a particular name or if it is just known as *multiple input*?

Comment: I know it as TextExt, but that's probably only the name of [the jQuery plugin for it](http://textextjs.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no particular name for it. [Inputs in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) can have a value of multiple email addresses separated by a comma:

```
<input type="email" value="foo@example.com, bar@example.com">
```

For what it's worth, the newer gmail compose UI uses a 1 row textarea inside a table instead of an actual "input"

[image: gmail compose UI]

Comment: I guess that makes the textarea easier to expand

Answer (score 1):

If any one is still looking for the answer there is a plugin which can be used over bootstrap

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

There is also an jquery plugin for adding multiple recipients along Email ID seperated by commas and this is the link

[Jquery Plugin for Multiple Email recipients](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Email-Address-Management-Multiple-Emails.html)